# How to lock orientation on splash screen Android Studio React Native layout.xml

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-layout

I have an app that needs all orientations unlocked for the app itself, but I want the splash screen to only be vertical. I have the orientation set in my layout.xml file, but you can *still* change the orientation while it's loading.

Here is my layout.xml file:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/red_logo"
        android:padding="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/text_logo_red"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/text_logo_red" />
</RelativeLayout>
```I have an app that needs all orientations unlocked for the app itself, but I want the splash screen to only be vertical. I have the orientation set in my layout.xml file, but you can *still* change the orientation while it's loading.

Here is my layout.xml file:
````

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/red_logo"
    android:padding="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/text_logo_red"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/text_logo_red" />
```

```

Is it open because the splash screen and the app are in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

using react native navigation you can lock the orientation on preferred screen

```
<Stack.Screen name="splash" component={Splash} options={{ orientation: 'portrait' }} />
```

Comment: The app hasn't spun up at that point. It's using the layout xml file defined in Android studio under .MainActivity.java